# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

i'm trying use spark graphx. before that i wanted to arrange my vertex and edge rdd using dataframes. for that purpose i used JavaRdd map function.but i'm getting above error.i tried various ways to fix this issue.i serialized tha whole class.but it didn't work.and also i implement Function and Serializable classes in one class ind used it in map function.but it aslo didn't work.please help me in advance.

```
    //add long unique id for vertex dataframe and get javaRdd
    JavaRDD<Row> ff = vertex_dataframe.javaRDD().zipWithIndex().map(new Function<Tuple2<Row, java.lang.Long>, Row>() {
        public Row call(Tuple2<Row, java.lang.Long> rowLongTuple2) throws Exception {
            return RowFactory.create(rowLongTuple2._1().getString(0), rowLongTuple2._2());
        }
    });
```

i serialized Function() class like below.

```
public abstract class SerialiFunJRdd<T1,R> implements Function<T1, R> , java.io.Serializable{
```

}

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to read something about serializing non static inner classes in java. you are creating a non static inner class here in your map which is not serialisable even if you mark that serialisable. you have to make it static first.

```
    JavaRDD<Row> ff = vertex_dataframe.javaRDD().zipWithIndex().map(mapFunc);

    static SerialiFunJRdd<Tuple2<Row, java.lang.Long>, Row> mapFunc=new SerialiFunJRdd<Tuple2<Row, java.lang.Long>, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Row call(Tuple2<Row, java.lang.Long> rowLongTuple2) throws Exception {
            return RowFactory.create(rowLongTuple2._1().getString(0), rowLongTuple2._2());
        }
    }
```